# Why are my PitchiPoy Knee and Elbow Directions wrong?

Tags: rigging, add-on, bones, rigify

I'm using the PitchiPoy addon for Rigify in Blender 2.72b to rig human characters. The knee and elbow joints are bending in random directions (this even differs between models) and I cannot find a system to this madness.

[image: Knee Joint Problem]

- The PitchiPoy *super_limb* does not use pole targets for IK bones
- I am getting different problems for different characters (eg. in one, the elbow is correct, in another it's bending sideways)
- I've tried changing the roll of the bones in edit mode, but this had no effect
- I've tried increasing the angle of knee and elbow hoping that's how Rigify figures out the bend direction, but this had no effect either

How do I control the *default* knee and elbow joint direction with PitchiPoy?
And why doesn't it use pole targets? I'd like to avoid changing the way this rig works by adding them for fear of breaking other things.

Comment: You need to increase the angle of the knee in the Metarig before you generate Pitchipoy. Your rig looks pretty much up & down where it should already look slightly relaxed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using rigify/pitchipoy in 2.79, if you click on the cog shape at the top of the legs or the arms an extra option shows up under rig main properties called pole_vector.

It's bascially a boolean (set it to 0 or 1), set it to 1 and you'll see normal pole targets again.

Comment: Thank you. Accepting this as the answer. I have stopped using PitchiPoy (reverted to Rigify due to numerous PitchiPoy issues), but it's good to know that PitchiPoy supports pole targets now. https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.79/Add-ons also states "Bone rolls are automatically calculated during the rig generation process, so no more eyeballing on the metarig's limbs bone rolls!" - this may change the outcome with my original model as well.

Answer (score 0):

See those big down-pointing arrows on either side of each thigh?  You have to select that widget and rotate it to get the functionality of pole targets. Same type of widgets at the upper arms to control the elbows.  Many people think this is superior to conventional pole targets.

Comment: That is easily found out, but it doesn't connect to my problem. If I rotated the leg 180 degrees at the point were the knee bends the wrong way, the kneecap and toes would point backwards :)